# Dynamicly creating and checking checkboxes in php

Tags: php, sql-server, dynamic, checkbox

I am trying to dynamically create php check-boxes linked to an MSSQL-Database. The idea is to List every item in the table, with a check box. From there the user will be able to check the check-boxes and click submit to change the value in 1 field of the Database to "A". I have the database linked to the php and It outputs the check-checkboxes and table values, however I do not know from there how to dynamically check the check-boxes to see if they are checked, or to use it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly the approach you want to take to dynamically create checkboxes. There are of course prettier ways to accomplish this (i.e. Smarty templates).

```
<html>
...
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
<?php
// connect to DB here

$result = mysql_query("SELECT l.id, l.name, u.checked FROM List l LEFT JOIN UserAnswers u ON l.id = u.list_id WHERE u.user_id = 5");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cb_' . $row['id'] . '" ' .
        'id="cb_' . $row['id'] . '" ';
    if($row['checked'])
        echo 'checked';
    echo " />\n"
    echo '<label for="cb_' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . "</label><br />\n";
}
?>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
</html>
```

submit.php is a bit trickier. When a checkbox is checked, it will set a post item. However if it's unchecked, you won't get ANYTHING back, so you need to check your database for all the items you'll be expecting.

```
<?php

// connect to DB here
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, checked FROM things");
$answers = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $checked = isset($_POST['cb_' + $row['id']]);
    $answers[$row['id']] = $checked;
}

// update your database here using $answers
foreach ($answers as $id => $checked)
{
    $query = "REPLACE INTO UserAnswers SET user_id=5, list_id=" . $id . ", checked=";
    if($checked)
        $query .= "1";
    else
        $query .= "0";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

This is all off the top of my head, there are better ways to do most of this. It's just a general direction. I make no guarantees about any of this. Oh and it looks quite vulnerable to SQL injection, watch out for that.

Comment: smarty is great if you hate yourself.

Comment: Dude, web programming in general is great if you hate yourself. I've never seen anything so needlessly complicated. To write a website you need to learn at least 4 different languages.

Comment: @Chris, okay, I'll rephrase.  Smarty is great if you want to hate yourself simultaneously in a language you know, a syntactically only marginally different interpreted version of that same language, as well as *an embedded version of the original language inside the second language.*  Forget that.

Comment: @Kerin agreed. Templating languages should look like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:StripHtmlFromText.gif

Comment: Man, I don't know if you're making fun of me or not.

Comment: I like the cut of your jib, Chris.  Meet me aboard me ship for ale and bawdy tales later.